# "mais mal" ou "pior"?

Tags: gramática, grau-comparativo

Estes dias, disse a um amigo:

> Tu conduzes **mais mal** do que eu.

E ele respondeu:

> Não é **mais mal** é **pior**.

Qual das duas formas é correta?

Onde poderíamos usar **mais mal** e/ou **pior** e porquê?

Estive a ver [Mais mal ou pior? - Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/mais-mal-ou-pior/11449) mas não fiquei esclarecido.

Comment: Para mim hoje é mais pior mal.

Comment: O pior mal é ser hoje.

Comment: Que é que não percebeste na resposta do ciberdúvidas? Parece-me bastante claro: "mais mal" usa-se quando "mal" precede um adjetivo verbal: "Tu conduzires é mais mal visto do que eu o fazer".

Comment: @Artefacto mas é mesmo só nesses casos?

Comment: Bom, segundo o Ciberdúvidas sim. Depois tenta explicar porque é que "cada vez mais mal à saúde" não soa mal. Claro que isto pressupõe uma definição de "correto" bastante normativista.

Comment: Ah e também quando "estiver integrado numa enumeração de qualidades atribuídas a um mesmo substantivo"

Comment: @Artefacto acho que uma resposta com exemplos seria bom, para mim, e para todos que tiverem a mesma  dúvida.

Comment: @Artefacto Em "cada vez mais mal à saúde" o "mal" está funcionando como um substantivo, não? Tipo "o mal"... Pelo que eu entendi, o "mais mal" não estão formando uma expressão, "cada vez mais" é a expressão que está qualificando "mal à saúde".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalmente no português original, utiliza-se sempre pior. Mais mal soa sempre mal. Contudo, é utilizado consoante o contexto.

Quando as pessoas querem usar mais mal é porque dá sempre para usar pior. Por exemplo: Fazes tudo mais mal que os outros. (Não é que esteja mal escrita a frase, mas apenas serve para ser mais subtil e dócil com a pessoa, porque dizer: Fazes tudo pior que os outros é uma frase mais agressiva, ou seja se digo pior quer dizer que de 0 a 10 a pessoa é um 0, enquanto que dizer mais mal significa que não é bom o suficiente, e é uma abordagem menos bruta e menos direta).

Também usa-se 'mais mal' antes dos adjetivos, como: mais mal agradecida; mais mal comportada( se quiséssemos qualificar o comportamento com pior seria: tem o pior comportamento[e comportamento é um nome])

Answer (score 8):

Nos círculos educados do Brasil, se tu disseres **"mais mal"**, serás logo corrigido por alguém, a não ser que logo em seguida venha um verbo adjetivado.

- mais mal feito, mais mal visto, mais mal encarado, mais mal falada.

> "Seu trabalho foi o mais mal feito de todos."
>
> "Ela é a mulher mais mal falada das redondezas."

Da mesma forma, em **pt-BR**, não dizemos "mais bom", "mais grande", ou "mais pequeno". Todas essas formas são consideradas erradas.

Quanto a **"faz mais mal à saúde"**, "mal" nesse caso não é um advérbio e sim um substantivo, **sinônimo de "danos"**.  ("Ele pratica o bem.", **"Não sabes o mal que ela me fez."**)

Answer (score 5):

Em geral, *pior* é a resposta correta.

Neste contexto, parece-me que o significado não é o mesmo. *Mais mal*, para mim, significa que os dois conduzem mal, um mais que o outro.  Enquanto usar *pior* não implica que o primeiro condutor conduz mal.

Comment: Ou seja mais mal seria correto nesse contexto, certo?

Comment: No caso em que ambos conduzem mal, parece-me que se usaria _ainda pior_.

Answer (score -2):

O mais correcto é "pior"; embora a outra opção também não esteja, de todo, incorrecta.

Answer (score -2):

Neste contexto, o correto é **pior**.

Comment: Justifique a sua resposta

Answer (score -2):

(Disclaimer: I'm not a native speaker of Brazilian Portuguese)

I'd argue that you'd be able to use "ruim" in this case rather than "mal/mau/má" and "pior" (which AFAIK is incorrect in this case).

So your sentence could become something like this:

"Cara, você dirige mais ruim do que eu mesmo!"

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The word "ruim" is a synonym of "mau" (evil, nasty, spoiled), not of "mal" (which is the opposite of "bem": well).